# How to export files from hard drive in Snow Leopard CD?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, terminal, hard-drive, startup

I have a macbook 5,1 that won't startup. I'm going to reinstall Snow Leopard with the CD, but is there a way to export some of the files that are in it? I can't seem to gain access to them through the terminal in the SL CD:

`cd Desktop` outputs  `No such file or directory`

and

`pwd` outputs  `var/root`

if I `cd ~/` then `ls`, there is only a Library folder, and no Users folder etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are booted to a different volume/system when you boot to the installer DVD.  With that in mind you can use "ls /Volumes" without the quotes to get a list of volume names.  Presumably you will see Macintosh HD (or different name if you renamed the internal volume) listed, if so you can use "cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD" to switch to the internal drive.  If your internal drive is named differently then keep in mind that spaces should be replaced with "\ " in Terminal.  Once you're in the correct volume your earlier commands should work as expected.

Comment: You might want to take out the HDD and attach it to a working computer with an USB connected HDD chassis or similar.

Comment: @MrRabbit, thank you so much, that worked. I can see the files. Now I just have to figure out how to copy them to an external drive.

Comment: @JackStewart No worries.  See my combined answer below for tips on copying your files to an external hard drive

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you are booted to a different volume/system when you boot to the installer DVD.

With that in mind you can use `ls /Volumes` to get a list of volume names.

Presumably you will see Macintosh HD (or different name if you renamed the internal volume) listed, if so you can use `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` to switch to the internal drive. If your internal drive is named differently then keep in mind that spaces should be replaced with `\` (a backslash followed by a space) in Terminal. Once you're in the correct volume your earlier commands should work as expected.

That same `ls /Volumes` command should show the path of your external hard drive as well.  You could copy the files using something along the lines of `cp /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/file1.jpg /Volumes/Backup\ Drive/Folder1`.

If you are attempting to copy everything from the hard drive you can use the following command to force a copy of everything, skipping over corrupted data that would otherwise cause the process to hang or stop...

```
cp -Rfv /original/data /destination/drive
```

or, following my previous example

```
cp -Rfv /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/ /Volumes/Backup\ Drive/
```